# Calculation of azure function monitoring pricing

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app

I have an azure function app which by default integrated with application insights app, now I can calculate the cost consumption of the function, but still cannot calculate monitoring cost.

how can I know or calculate monitoring cost?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "Cost Management" in azure portal.

Nav to azure portal -> in the left blade, click "Cost Management + Billing" -> then in the new page, click "Cost Management". Screenshot as below:

[image]

**Then** in the "Cost Management" page -> click "Cost analysis" -> "Cost by resource" -> then Mouse over the "Resource Type" column -> then the filter button occurs, click the filter button and input "application insights", and locate your application insights, you can see the cost. Screenshot as below:

[image]

If your application insights is not listed here, means that no cost as of now. Because application insights is free for "5 GB per customer per month". Details are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/), in the "Application Insights" section. A screenshot from that site:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I have an other inquiry, "GB per customer per month" what it means, My azure function consumes data from Iot hub, Is GB/month = total size of data consumed by the function ?

Comment: no, it means the monitor data sent to application insights. You can see in your post -> the screenshot, when click the "monitor" in azure function, there're the monitor data.

Comment: Where is the size of data in my screen shot ?

Comment: @Walid, in your screenshot, you can only see the messages which are sent to application insights, as you can see there're only some text message, no size there.  If you want to check the size, you can go to your application insights in azure portal -> in the left blade, click "usage and estimated costs" to check the total size, details are in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#understand-your-usage-and-estimate-costs).

Answer (score 0):

It is charged based on data size and consumption. You can have a look at the [`Azure Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/usage-estimated-costs#azure-monitor-pricing-model) pricing model in order to get a detailed idea.